# How can I split this list when there's a double new line?

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list:

```
['Madame\n', 'Abba\n', '123321\n', '$a3 Ã\xa0 3A$\n', '\n', 
     'Radar\n', 'aBAb (en)\n', 'Sagas\n', 'Wow\n', '12345']
```

I want to separate it into two lists, where there is a "double newline", i.e. after the fourth object.

```
['Madame\n', 'Abba\n', '123321\n', '$a3 Ã\xa0 3A$\n']

['Radar\n', 'aBAb (en)\n', 'Sagas\n', 'Wow\n', '12345']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
file = ['Madame\n', 'Abba\n', '123321\n', '$a3 Ã\xa0 3A$\n', '\n', 'Radar\n', 'aBAb     (en)\n', 'Sagas\n', 'Wow\n', '12345']

part1 = file[0:file.index('\n')]
part2 = file[file.index('\n') + 1:]
```

Hope this is what your looking for :D